# Inequality with two unknown quantities

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality

I am trying to find solutions for the following inequality

$$e^{\frac{|x|}{\alpha}}  > \frac{x^2}{\alpha} + 1$$

where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^+$. The expressions are clearly equal when $x=0$, so we are interested in solutions in $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$. It is trivial to reduce the inequality to

$$|x|  > \ln(\frac{x^2}{\alpha} + 1)\alpha$$

where we can assume $x>0$, $x<0$ and solve for both assumptions. However, I do not see a clear way to proceed with

$$e^x  > (\frac{x^2 + \alpha}{\alpha})^\alpha$$

which sprouts from the assumption $x >0$.

Comment: Expand $e^x$ it helps

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no explicit solution.

By parity of the functions, we may assume that $x \ge 0$.

When $0 \le x <1$, we have $x^2 < x $, so $e^{x/a} \ge e^{x^2/a} \ge 1 + x^2/a$.

When $x$ is large enough, $e^{x/a} \ge 1 + x^2/a$ by compared growth.

Yet, for some values of $a>0$, there may exist some interval on which the inverse inequality holds.

To be more precise, to compare $x/a$ and $\ln(1+x^2/a)$, we may study the function $f_a : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_a(x) = x/a - \ln(1+x^2/a)$. We have
$$f_a'(x) = 1/a - \frac{2x/a}{1+x^2/a} = \frac{1}{a} - \frac{2x}{a+x^2} = \frac{a+x^2-2ax}{a(a+x^2)}.$$
The discriminant of the numerator is $4a^2-4a=4a(a-1)$.

If $a \le 1$, $f_a'$ is always positive, excepted at $x=1$ if $a=1$, so $f_a$ is increasing, so $f_a(x)>f_a(0)=0$for $x>0$.

If $a>1$, the numerator $x^2-2ax+a$ has two distinct positive roots $x_1(a)<x_2(a)$ (and we have explicit formulas for them), $f_a'$ is negative when $x \in ]x_1(a),x_2(a)[$, positive when $x \notin [x_1(a),x_2(a)]$. One deduces the variations of $f_a$. To know whether $f_a$ takes negative values, it suffices to look at the sign of $f_a(x_2(a))$, but determining this sign looks hard. And when it is negative, determine the interval on which $f_a$ is negative is not explicit.